# What's the name of the little widget with three dots inside a cardview in android?

Tags: android, google-play, popupmenu, android-imagebutton

[image]

What's the little widget with three dots? How can I add it to my app?

Comment: ⋮- that character is also called "vertical ellipsis"

Comment: the three vertical dots are called ActionMenu in Android and the icon in Flutter is more_vert

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This is not a widget at all. It is an `ImageButton` (borderless in style) using the overflow Icon that includes a `PopupMenu`

For documentation tutorial visits http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu

This refers to a nice code snippet from the link above:

```
  <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:src="@drawable/ic_overflow_holo_dark"
       android:contentDescription="@string/descr_overflow_button"
       android:onClick="showPopup" />
```

Then use to show popup:

```
 public void showPopup(View v) {
     PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
     MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
     popup.show();
 }
```

**3-Dots button is available among Assets in Android Studio:**

Right click on `res` -> New -> Vector Assets -> Asset Type = Clip Art

-> Click on the button next to Clip Art: label -> Search for ***more vert***

[image]

Comment: added a link to the correct one using that tool above @Cristian

Comment: @Laurent see under UPDATE

Answer (score 56):

You may also simply use an `ImageButton` with the `actionOverflowButtonStyle` style attribute.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="?android:attr/actionOverflowButtonStyle"/>
```

Comment: easiest answer, most helpful one. should be #1.

Answer (score 4):

The "original" three dot widget is the `android.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.OverflowMenuButton` ([ActionMenuPresenter.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/ActionMenuPresenter.java)). Sadly it is a private class. Here a working shorter version:

```
public class OverflowMenuButton extends AppCompatImageView
{
    public OverflowMenuButton(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public OverflowMenuButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public OverflowMenuButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.OverflowButtonTheme), attrs, R.attr.actionOverflowButtonStyle);

        setClickable(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Themes of the `ContextThemeWrapper` to get a dark and light version:

```
<!--White dots theme-->
<style name="OverflowButtonTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>

<!--Dark dots theme-->
<style name="OverflowButtonThemeLight" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I've found on the web, it is called "overflow icon" or action overflow".

This code maybe could help you. (The code is from [there](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_and_Managing_Overflow_Menus_on_Android#The_Overflow_Menu))

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_red"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/red_string"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_green"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/green_string"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zm0,2c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2s0.9,2 2,2 2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zm0,6c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2s0.9,2 2,2 2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2z"/>
</vector>
```